# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [vsj.properties] is not valid

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-services

I'm using **Tomcat 8.0.21** and I define a filter in web.xml using Vintela.
I'm logged on Windows (Server 2012) with a local user (LOCALHOST/UserA).
I create a **Windows service** for Tomcat starting with a **domain user** login (DOMAIN/UserB),

But when I start it then Tomcat cannot init my filter :

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter authFilter
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The resource path [vsj.properties] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:250)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResourceAsStream(ApplicationContext.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResourceAsStream(ApplicationContextFacade.java:210)
    at com.wedgetail.idm.sso.AbstractAuthenticator.getResource(AbstractAuthenticator.java:2107)
    at com.wedgetail.idm.sso.AbstractAuthenticator.getPropsFromFile(AbstractAuthenticator.java:2069)
    at com.wedgetail.idm.sso.AuthFilter.init(AuthFilter.java:129)
    at com.myfilter.MyFilter.init(MyFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4573)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5192)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1096)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1756)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
```

(*'vsj.properties' doesn't exist (it is optional for Vintela)*)

But if I start Tomcat manually (startup.bat) with the current **local user** session, then it works fine (?!).

Why ?

The behavior is different depending on whether the service is launched with DOMAIN User or manually with local User....

Thanks,

N.B. : I've already read http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201410.mbox/

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigations and debugging, I have the same errors with either Domain user or local user.

My error was to not see error occuring on the console :(

But now to resolve my issue, I set a new (system) property of Tomcat 8 to return **null** if resource file name is not **well-formated** instead to have a java exception :

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.GET_RESOURCE_REQUIRE_SLASH=true
```

Now Vintela works...